# $f$ is continuous and closed $\Longleftrightarrow \overline{f(E)} = f(\overline{E})$ for all $E \subseteq M$

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Let $(M,d)$ and $(N,d')$ be metric spaces and let $f:M \rightarrow N$ be a function.

I want to show that $f$ is continuous and closed $\Longleftrightarrow \overline{f(E)} = f(\overline{E})$ for all $E \subseteq M$.

I have already proved that $f$ is continuous if and only if $f(\overline{E}) \subseteq \overline{f(E)}$ for all $E \subseteq M$, and also that $\overline{f(E)} = f(\overline{E})$ for all $E \subseteq M \Longrightarrow f$ is continuous and closed.

I am only missing $f$ is continuous and closed $\Longrightarrow \overline{f(E)} \subseteq f(\overline{E})$ for all $E \subseteq M$.

I would really appreciate some help. Thanks!

Comment: When you say *closed*, you mean $f$ is a *closed* map right?

Comment: Yes :)
I don't mean this in a rude way: is there another meaning? I am just asking to know if there are other definitions with which I can get confused in the future.

Comment: Or did you mean that "$f$ is a closed map" is the correct expression for what I meant by "$f$ is closed"?

Answer (score 1):

As I remember, a closed map is a function which maps closed sets to closed sets. So, you have $f(\bar{E})$ is a closed set.

You already proved that $f(\bar{E}) \subseteq \overline{f(E)} \subseteq \overline{f(\bar{E})}$. But, we know that $\overline{f(\bar{E})}$ is the smallest closed set contain $f(\bar{E})$, then $\overline{f(\bar{E})} \subseteq f(\bar{E})$.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't understand how is a proof for all $E \subseteq M$.